# Python lxml does not support xpath syntax 'starts-with'?

Tags: python, xpath, lxml

```
str = """<ROOT>
<ITEM>
   <REVENUE_YEAR>2554-02</REVENUE_YEAR>
   <REGION>Central</REGION>
</ITEM>
<ITEM>
  <REVENUE_YEAR>2552-02</REVENUE_YEAR>
  <REGION>Central</REGION>
</ITEM>
<ITEM>
  <REVENUE_YEAR>2552-03</REVENUE_YEAR>
  <REGION>Central</REGION>
</ITEM>
</ROOT>"""

xml = etree.fromstring(str)
xpath_str = ".//ITEM[starts-with(REVENUE_YEAR,'2554')]"
result = xml.find(xpath_str)
print(result)
```

Hi, the code above raised SyntaxError: invalid predicate, does it mean lxml do not support starts-with? Any other way to locate the REVENUE_YEAR element(2554-02) by xpath with lxml? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It supports xpath but you need to use xpath:

```
str = """<ROOT>
<ITEM>
   <REVENUE_YEAR>2554-02</REVENUE_YEAR>
   <REGION>Central</REGION>
</ITEM>
<ITEM>
  <REVENUE_YEAR>2552-02</REVENUE_YEAR>
  <REGION>Central</REGION>
</ITEM>
<ITEM>
  <REVENUE_YEAR>2552-03</REVENUE_YEAR>
  <REGION>Central</REGION>
</ITEM>
</ROOT>"""

xml = etree.fromstring(str)
xpath_str = ".//ITEM[starts-with(REVENUE_YEAR,'2554')]"
result = xml.xpath(xpath_str)
print(result) # which is a list containing only one element
```